Issue: slots Field in Typings for Svelte Component Testing
I am building a Svelte component library for my project and have run into several issues, particularly when trying to test components with slots. Here's the error I'm facing:
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'slots' does not exist in type 'SvelteComponentOptions<SvelteComponent

stackblitz example
From what I understand, the slots field should exist according to the typings in svelte-shims.d.ts. However, my test setup seems to contradict this when I try to use the Svelte Testing Library example for slots testing
svelte-shims.d.ts
svelte-testing-library - example slots
Other problems but I managed to find workaround along the way.
(!) [plugin typescript] src/index.ts (2:35): @rollup/plugin-typescript TS2307: Cannot find module './Button.svelte'

To resolve this, I had to explicitly add import 'svelte'; in src/index.ts file.

When trying to use vite@5.4.10, it threw an error complaining about a missing src/app.html file. I eventually switched to Rollup for bundling.


Any thoughts?
I appreciate any insights or suggestions.
vitest.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'
import { sveltePreprocess } from 'svelte-preprocess'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
    import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte';
import { sveltePreprocess } from 'svelte-preprocess';

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => ({
    plugins: [
        svelte({
            hot: !process.env.VITEST,
            preprocess: [sveltePreprocess({ typescript: true })]
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        conditions: mode === 'test' ? ['browser'] : [],
    },
    test: {
        globals: true,
        environment: 'jsdom',
    },
}));

Button.svelte
<script lang="ts">
    export let onClick: () => void = () => {};
</script>
  

<button on:click={onClick}>
    <slot></slot>
</button>

Button.test.ts
import { getByText, render, waitFor  } from '@testing-library/svelte';
import Button from './Button.svelte';
import { describe, it, expect } from "vitest";

describe('Button', () => {

    it("it should render", async () => {
    const text = "Submit";

    const { getByText } = render(Button, { 
        slots: { default: text },
    });

    expect(getByText(text)).toBeInTheDocument();

    })
  
});

tsconfig.json
{
    "extends": "@tsconfig/svelte/tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
      "allowJs": true,
      "checkJs": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "strict": true,
      "moduleResolution": "bundler",
      "types": ["vitest/globals", "@testing-library/jest-dom"]
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules/*"],
}

rollup.config.js
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import terser from '@rollup/plugin-terser';
import { sveltePreprocess } from "svelte-preprocess";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';

const { default: { name: pkg_name, module, main }} = await import('./package.json', { with: { type: "json" }, });

const name = pkg_name
    .replace(/^(@\S+\/)?(svelte-)?(\S+)/, '$3')
    .replace(/^\w/, m => m.toUpperCase())
    .replace(/-\w/g, m => m[1].toUpperCase());

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH

export default {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: [
        {
            sourcemap: true,
            format: 'cjs',
            file: main,
        },
        {
            sourcemap: true,
            format: 'esm',
            file:  module,
        }
    ],
    plugins: [
        svelte({
            preprocess: sveltePreprocess({ sourceMap: true }),
            compilerOptions: {
                dev: !production
            },
            emitCss: false,
        }),
        resolve({
            browser: true,
            dedupe: ['svelte']
        }),
        terser(),
        json(),
        typescript({
            sourceMap: true,
            declaration: true,
            outDir: "dist",
            exclude: ['**/*.test.ts', '**/*.spec.ts', '**/__tests__/**']
        }),
    ]
};

package.json
{
  "name": "web-component",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "module": "dist/index.mjs",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",  
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup --config",
    "test": "vitest",
    "coverage": "vitest run --coverage"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "files": [
    "src",
    "dist"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-json": "^6.1.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.3.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-terser": "0.4.4",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^12.1.1",
    "@tsconfig/svelte": " ^5.0.4",
    "rollup": "^4.28.1",
    "rollup-plugin-filesize": "^10.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^7.2.2",
    "svelte-check": "^4.1.1",
    "svelte-preprocess": "^6.0.3",
    "tslib": "^2.8.1",
    "typescript": "^5.7.2",
    "vitest": "^2.1.8",
    "jsdom": "^25.0.1",
    "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "^4.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.6.3",
    "@testing-library/svelte": "^5.2.4",
    "@vitest/coverage-v8": "^2.1.8"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "svelte": "^5.8.1"
  }
}


